# Why isn't Mulan's wound far worse than it actually is?

Tags: disney, mulan

Towards the end of the "avalanche battle" Shan Yu swings his sword and cuts Mulan across her stomach. A few minutes later, we see Mulan hurt and bleeding from the cut which is **round and small compared to the arc of Shan Yu's swing.**

**Am I missing something? Does it make sense for the wound to be that small?**

I thought that Shan Yu was possibly too far away with the horse to cut Mulan properly. But looking at the scene, it looks like he is pretty close. So close,  in fact, that his swing looks far more more deadly that it actually was.

Comment: Well you know, it's probably a stuntwoman who is really good at getting hurt less than it looks on camera. Also the whole animated/cartoon thing might be a factor.

Comment: @MischaRosnach - I heard that cartoon Mulan did all her own stunts.

Comment: I support Valorum's answer, but I have to say it:"Because Disney."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's really not clear how she injured herself. As you can see from the clip below, the sword actually misses her(!). That being said, I think we can reasonably assume that the intention was that her [lamellar armour](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Kh-to448NTEC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=chinese%20armour%20fifth%20century&source=bl&ots=Rvt0UKUDAq&sig=SlJFzkWswfs4-8zbY-qoGypMviY&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4vMvMj4HQAhXML8AKHYXCAFwQ6AEIXzAP#v=onepage&q=chinese%20armour%20fifth%20century&f=false) (e.g. fabric over plates of hard leather) was at least slightly effective in warding off the majority of the cut.

Her injury isn't shown, but given the lack of an obvious cut, it may simply have been a blunt injury (a laceration) that broke the skin and started bleeding.

[image]

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that even cloth (particularly silk, something almost stereotypically common in depictions of the Chinese in media) does a good job of defending against slashing wounds because the cloth, if it does not immediately break, bunches up along the blade, turning a deep cut into a shallower one with more bruising.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's not especially clear what type of armour she's wearing. I've plumped for lamellar because it's period-appropriate, matches the images on the screen and would be sufficient to ward off a cutting strokes but thin enough that she could still suffer an impact laceration.